# How to capture button click from customized QMessageBox?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside

How can I modify the code for the customized QMessageBox below in order to know whether the user clicked 'yes' or 'no'?

```
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

# Create a somewhat regular QMessageBox
msgBox = QtGui.QMessageBox( QtGui.QMessageBox.Question, "My title", "My text.", QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No )

# Get the layout
question_layout = msgBox.layout()

# Additional widgets to add to the QMessageBox
qlabel_workspace_project = QtGui.QLabel('Some random data window:')
qtextedit_workspace_project = QtGui.QTextEdit()
qtextedit_workspace_project.setReadOnly(True)

# Add the new widgets
question_layout.addWidget(qlabel_workspace_project,question_layout.rowCount(), 0, 1, question_layout.columnCount() )
question_layout.addWidget(qtextedit_workspace_project,question_layout.rowCount(), 0, 1, question_layout.columnCount() )

# Show widget
msgBox.show()
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Instead of `show` you should rather use the `exec_` method, that all widgets inheriting from `QDialog` have:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qmessagebox.html#exec

This method blocks until the msgbox was closed and returns the result:

```
result = msgBox.exec_()
if result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
    # do yes-action
else:
    # do no-action
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `msgBox.exec_()`, i.e., run it as a dialog. The call has a return value equal to the button that was pressed, compare with `QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes` or `QtGui.QMessageBox.No`.

Alternatively, if you don't want to run this modally, but either have a callback or poll the message-box regularly, the following will return the button that was clicked (or None if nothing was clicked yet or 0 if the message-box was closed without a button click):

```
msgBox.clickedButton()
```

Note that this returns the button instance, and you'll have to figure out yourself which button that is.

The `buttonClicked()` signal does something similar.

Answer (score 0):

For the non-modal option, mdurant/jesterjunk answer is correct, however for completion this is how you got the standard button value:

```
result = msgBox.standardButton(msgBox.clickedButton())
if result == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
    # do yes-action
else:
    # do no-action
```